# $\lim \frac{\cos{x}}{x^2}$ as x goes to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\cos{x}}{x^2} =\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{d}{dx} \cos{x}}{\frac{d}{dx}x^2} = -\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\sin{x}}{x}$. But $-\frac{1}{x} \le \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \le \frac{1}{x}$ so $\displaystyle -\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{x} \le \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\sin{x}}{x} \le \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{x} \iff 0 \le \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\sin{x}}{x} \le 0 \iff \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\sin{x}}{x} = 0.$

Therefore $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\cos{x}}{x^2} = 0.$

Is the above correct?

Comment: You can use the bound $\frac{-1}{x^{2}} \leqslant \frac{\cos x}{x^{2}} \leqslant \frac{1}{x^{2}}$ to start.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct but more complicated than it needs to be.  $|\cos x|\le 1$, $\lim 1/x^2=0$ suffices.

Comment: You can only use L'Hopital if it is $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$.  This is neither.

Comment: @Michael  I have checked Baby Rudin 5.13.  Per that section, L'Hopital's rule applies to anything$/\pm\infty$.  Thus, the reasoning above still seems correct to me, just overly complicated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must not apply L'Hospital's rule in this case! L'Hospital is only applicable for limits with $\infty \over \infty$ or $0 \over 0$ expressions.

Nonetheless,  you can easily get to the limit knowing that $\mid\cos x \mid  \leq 1$, thus $$\frac{\mid\cos x\mid}{x^2} \leq \frac{1}{x^2} \xrightarrow{\: n \to \infty \: } 0$$

Comment: Good catch and Well answered.

Comment: Good catch! (+1)

Answer (score 3):

You arrived at the correct answer, but your first step is incorrect.

Here is another method:

Note that $\cos(x)$ is bounded and $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{x^2}=0$$ And you're done.

Comment: how is l'hospital correct? Is it $0 \over 0$ or $\infty \over \infty$?

Comment: @addy2012 You are absolutely correct. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\left|\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\right|\le \frac{1}{x^2}\to 0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

L'hospital rule is not correct in this case as noticed by @addy2012.

You may observe that you could conclude directly, as $x \to \infty$, by the squeeze theorem:
$$
\left|\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\right|\leq \frac1{x^2}.
$$

Comment: usage of l'hospital is not correct...

Comment: @addy2012 Oops, you are right! I will edit my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to use the derivatives: For every $x > 0$ we have
$$
 -\frac{1}{x^2} \leq \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2} \leq \frac{1}{x^2}.
$$
Because $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x^2} = 0$ it follows that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2} = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to many other answers (including the accepted answer by adjan) your method is correct. L'Hospital's Rule is applicable for indeterminate forms like $0/0$ and "$\text{anything}/\pm\infty$".

However the use of L'Hospital's Rule is totally unnecessary here and the limit is evaluated more easily by applying "Squeeze theorem" on the inequality $$-\frac{1}{x^{2}}\leq \frac{\cos x}{x^{2}} \leq \frac{1}{x^{2}}$$